# Run Ubuntu and Windows 10 on same laptop

Tags: 14.04

Run Ubuntu and Windows 10 on same laptop - can it be done. Thanks

Comment: This question gets asked every day 20 times at least. Please check before asking.

Comment: Wozza, you seem to be very new. In my opinion the best way to first install Ubuntu is following a tutorial on youtube step by step. Find someone that did a dual boot on your laptop model.

Comment: Yes. Bash on windows, live boot, or dual boot. Post a more specific question if you have problems. Be sure to back up you data and read and understand both the ubuntu install guide(s) and linux partitioning conventions BEFORE you try to install / dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am running one in dual boot. I would recommend reserving some free HD space in the windows disk management space, so that you can run Ubuntu on an Ext filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Besides for dual boot you can run Ubuntu from pendrive, it is a good way to test Ubuntu on your laptop without modifying the hard drive.

You can use the same pendrive to install Ubuntu to your computer when you wish.

**UNetbootin** is usually a good creating tool for Windows https://unetbootin.github.io/, for Linux there is **mkusb** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb.